# How can I do the addEventListener function while I choose the right canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I had created some canvas base on the div number. That means the total div number like a random number.
If I created 5 div and using createElement("canvas") base on div number, How can I use addEventListener for the right canvas?
Take an example, I want to draw a line on the second canvas using mousedown event. I want to draw a line on the first canvas after finished drawing a line on second canvas.

Here is my Coding:

```
  for (i = 0; i < DivNumber; i++){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    continer.appendChild(canvas)
    canvas.height = window.height
    canvas.width = window.width
  }
  canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas')[numPages]
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  for (const ev of ["touchstart", "mousedown"]) {
    canvas.addEventListener(ev, Start)
  }
  
  for (const ev of ['touchmove', 'mousemove']) {
    canvas.addEventListener(ev, move)
  }
  
  for (const ev of ['touchend', 'touchleave', 'mouseup']) {
    canvas.addEventListener(ev, End)
  };
```

Comment: I don't follow 100%. Do you want to add those listeners to *every* canvas? Or just a specific one?

Comment: @ChrisG I think he wants the second canvas to duplicate the drawing on the first as it's being drawn.

Comment: @ChrisG In this case, I only can draw a line on first canvas. How can I draw another canvas?

Comment: You could just move those three for loops inside the first for loop. It has a `canvas` variable, so that should work fine. `querySelectorAll` returns a list of matches; you cannot use the result to do stuff to multiple elements at once, that only works with jQuery.

Comment: @ChrisG I moved those three for loop inside the first loop. But it can't work

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/b6z4ot19/

Comment: Do you mean canvas that superpose themselves or canvas that are next to each other ?

Comment: @codeanjero I try to do all canvaslike the first canvas: https://jsfiddle.net/fcyk5mgx/

Comment: @ChrisG want all canvas like the first canvas : jsfiddle.net/fcyk5mgx

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem is that you are not calculating the canvas coordinate. In your app, all canvases are as big as the window, so for the 2nd canvas, the pageX and pageY coordinates will no longer be inside the canvas. You need to subtract the top-left corner of the canvas element in order to get canvas coordinates for drawing. Note that inside an event handler function, `e.target` is the current canvas. You can use that to get its coordinates, and to get the canvas's context.

Comment: @ChrisG Oh, I just fixed it all. But How can I make all the canvas having the same Start/Move/End function with addEventListner?

Comment: [My comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384931/how-can-i-do-the-addeventlistener-function-while-i-choose-the-right-canvas#comment113851021_64384931) describes how to do that. It should already work. Like I said, use `e.target` inside the event to get the current canvas.